# In JSF 2 - Trying to rerender a panelgroup that is between 2 ui:repeats

Tags: jsf-2

The best way to illustrate what i'm trying to do is just give an example:

```
<h:form prependid="false" >
    <h:panelGroup id="layer1">
        <ui:repeat>
            <h:panelGroup id="layer2>
                <ui:repeat>
                    <h:panelGroup id="layer3">
                        <h:commandButton>
                            <f:ajax render="layer2" execute="@form" />
                        </h:commandButton>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </ui:repeat>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

When pressing the `h:commandButton` in the example above I get an exception from JSF saying that the ID `layer2` does not exists.

How can I do this correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work out for this:

```
<f:ajax render=":#{component.parent.parent.parent.parent.clientId}:layer2" execute="@form" />
```

It works in MyFaces only, not in Mojarra (yet). Its `<ui:repeat>` is broken in many ways.

Comment: Great Thanks! (Using MyFaces) I wish there was a more "streamlined" way of doing this..

Comment: I too. Note that `render=":#{component.parent.parent.parent.clientId}"` should in theory work, but it doesn't. Also, `<h:panelGroup binding="#{layer2}">` with `render=":#{layer2.clientId}"` should in theory work, but it doesn't. Both approaches works in both MyFaces/Mojarra when `<ui:repeat>` doesn't come into picture. So it's perhaps also a *bit* broken in MyFaces.