# component to self refresh in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I am creating a table component using JSF and html table (no other faces table involved), so collection is taken as parameter and it iterates and display the table contents.

I have a "Remove" link on click of which it should remove the items and it's working fine. My problem now is after the item is removed I need to self-refresh the table component.

It worked when I used @form in the render. But that would be an issue when integrating the component with any page. Anyone has ideas to self-refresh the table component on click of the "Remove" link? Please provide your thoughts.

```
      <a4j:commandLink id="removeSelection" actionListener="#{cc.attrs.rowRemoveEventListener}" render="@form #{cc.attrs.renderOnRemove}" styleClass="st-remove-link" onclick="">
        <f:param name="rowKey" value="#{rowKey}"/>
        <span class="link-text">Remove</span>
        <a4j:ajax event="click" render="#{cc.clientId}" />
      </a4j:commandLink>
```

The full component markup:

```
    <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
      <--stylesheet link here-->
      <h:panelGroup id="simpletablepanel" layout="block">
        <a4j:outputPanel id="simpletablebody" layout="block">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
               <span>value</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a4j:commandLink id="removeSelection"
                actionListener="#{cc.attrs.rowRemoveEventListener}"
                render=":#{cc.clientId} #{cc.attrs.renderOnRemove}">
                  <f:param name="rowKey" value="#{rowKey}"/>
                  <span>Remove</span>
              </a4j:commandLink>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </ui:fragment>
    </table>
  </a4j:outputPanel>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you wrapped your component in a `<div id="#{cc.clientId}">` already? (See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313207/referring-to-a-composite-component-from-a-using-page-fails))

Comment: yes tried that. It just refreshes the form but not the component itself. I removed <a4j:ajax> and passed #{cc.clientId} in render of <a4j:commandLink>. Still nothing worked.

Comment: Can you post the full component code?

Comment: You are prepending the clientId with `:` in the render attribute, this qualifies it an absolute component path, not what you want. Use just `render="#{cc.clientId}"` instead.

Comment: sorry that was a try with hard coded Id , I removed it and tried but still same result

Comment: even tried execute="#{cc.clientId}" still no change

Comment: hmm... I had some problems previously using these Richfaces tags. Could you try using the plain JSF ones? Try changing your `a4j:commandLink` to: `<h:commandLink action="#{cc.attrs.rowRemoveEventListener}" value="Remove"> <f:param name="rowKey" value="#{rowKey}"/>  <f:ajax render="#{cc.clientId}" /> </h:commandLink>`, let's see what happens?

Comment: btw, what do you have in the `rowRemoveEventListener` method?

Comment: ok i will give it a try. rowRemoveEventListener is a callback method. That gets triggered perfectly.

Comment: You should re-render the panel that encloses the table, causing the table to rebuild. One possible approach when using vanilla html tables is to handle your `<tr>` elements to show the records. The backing bean should contain a list of the records that you can iterate through with, for example, `<a4j:repeat>` and in the end, each delete link should trigger a table update by re-rendering the container panel.

Comment: Thanks to you all, especially elias. Issue resolved.

Comment: The rendering using render=":#{cc.clientId} #cc.attrs.renderOnRemove}" was creating the problem. #{cc.clientId} was refreshing correctly but the next id that is passed was wrong and it was blocking the complete reRender. Correcting that id and wrapping the component with <div id="#{cc.clientId}"> and adding execute="#{cc.clientId}" to the commanLink fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

just check the below link, i hope you will found something..

[In JSF 2 - Trying to rerender a panelgroup that is between 2 ui:repeats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818217/in-jsf-2-trying-to-rerender-a-panelgroup-that-is-between-2-uirepeats)